# The variable `X` in a parfor cannot be classified in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I have a `parfor loop` like this:

```
parfor i=1:20

for j=1:5
%% Some codes

[~,~,~,AUC]=perfcurve(testTargets,testOutputs,'1');

AUC_T(i)=AUC;

end

%% averaging between AUC_Ts in outputs of j=1:5

end
```

I have this error after running this code:

```
The variable AUC_T in a parfor cannot be classified.
See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Overview".
```

I want store AUC values and use it afrer `parfor loop`. What is the problem and how can i solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you used parfor before?  If not, you may want to read the docs or a summary: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/10/02/using-parfor-loops-getting-up-and-running/#12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
parfor i=1:20

for j=1:5
%% Some codes

[~,~,~,AUC]=perfcurve(testTargets,testOutputs,'1');

AUC_T(i,j)=AUC;

end

end

%% averaging between AUC_T values
```

We should set averaging after `parfor` loop.

Thank you Michael Graczyk for your commnet and answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure without being able to see more of the code, but you can probably solve your problem by using a cell array to store the results:

```
parfor i=1:20
    ...
    AUC_T{i}=AUC;
end
```

Or more simply, you can explicitly specify the result shape:

```
AUC_T(i, :) = AUC;
```

Comment: It didn't solve the problem. I'm training a neural network in `parfor` loop. I can store `trained net` with `Net{m)=trained_net` but I have this problem only with `AUC` !

Comment: + I added more information to main question. thanks.